# Various plugins for the different entrypoints

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to make webpack collect two files with different set of plug-ins.
I imagined it like this:

```
{
    entry: {
      name: "./first",
      output: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
          filename: "first.js"
      },
      plugins: [
          new FirstPlugin ()
      ],
    },
    entry: {
      name: "./second",
          path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
          filename: "second.js"
      },
      plugins: [
          new AnotherPlugin ()
      ]
    }
}
```

But it is certainly not working.
Is it possible to get current entripoint into the pluging runtime? Then everything would be decided one IF.

Answer (score 0):

If you are operating on two different entry points and outputs, you can simply run two different webpack processes like so (simplified).

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = [
{
    name: 'first',
    entry: {
      main: "./first"
    }
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
          filename: "first.js"
    },
    plugins: [
          new FirstPlugin ()
      ]
    }
},
{
    name: 'second',
    entry: {
      main: "./second"
    }
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
          filename: "second.js"
    },
    plugins: [
          new SecondPlugin ()
      ]
    }
}
];
```